# Time limit exceeded on ideone but not on code block

Tags: c++, memory-management, dictionary, stl

I have this code which relates to BUSYMAN problem of SPOJ.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<map>

int main()
{
    int cases, i, j, act, answer, temp1, temp2;
    scanf("%d",&cases);

    for(i=0; i<cases; i++)
    {
        answer = 0;
        scanf("%d", &act);
        std::multimap<int, int> mymap;

        for(j=0; j<act; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&temp1);
            scanf("%d",&temp2);
            mymap.insert(std::pair<int,int>(temp2, temp1));;
        }

        std::multimap<int,int>::iterator it;
        temp1 = (mymap.begin())->second;

        while(mymap.size() != 0)
        {
            it = mymap.begin();
            if(it->second < temp1)
            {
                mymap.erase(it);
                continue;
            }

            answer++;
            temp1 = it->first;
            mymap.erase(mymap.begin());

            if(mymap.size() != 0)
            {
                it = mymap.begin();
                while(it->second < temp1)
                {
                    mymap.erase(it);
                    it = mymap.begin();
                }
            }
        }

        printf("%d\n",answer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is running on code block and giving the correct answer = 3 for the test case :

```
1
6
7 9 0 10 4 5 8 9 4 10 5 7
```

but for the same test case I am getting time limit exceeded on ideone.com and even on spoj.

For the rest of the test cases given on SPOJ, it is working fine on ideone as well as code block.
Is it going in infinite loop or is there some other problem?
And how do we allocate memory for multimap because in this question act can have a max value of 100000 which, I think, will cause buffer overflow?

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle bug in your code.

What happens if just before the line `while(it->second < temp1)` is executed, mymap size is zero, that is it has no elements within it. Where are you checking for this eventuality?

Note that it CAN happen (and it DOES happen in the test case you presented), considering that you keep removing the element pointed to by the iterator *it*, and then setting it to the first element of the map.

In such a scenario as presented by your test case, ultimately there won't be any first element left, so *it* will eventually point to the end of the map, for which you unfortunately have no check in the *while* loop.

That's where your code ends into infinite loop. If you change it to

```
while(it!=mymap.end() && it->second < temp1)
```

, it might perhaps give you the correct result.